# How to set volume control using uislider in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudioplayer, uislider, xcode4.6

.h file
 IBOutlet UISlider *valume;
AVAudioPlayer * player;

```
-(IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)slider;
```

.m file

```
-(IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)slider{


}
```

how to set volume maximum and minimum using uislider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)slider{

    player.volume=slider.value;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

or

```
-(IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)slider{

    player.volume=slider.value;
}
```

its work for me :)