# how to handle volume slider position in AVAudioplayer in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, avaudioplayer

I am creating little app that uses `AVAudioplayer` to play on audio list. I am trying to save the current volume position of the player so when he return back to audio view the volume slider will be on same position when he left off. I am trying to write some code but I don't know how to handle this functionality. Here's what I tried:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad

{

UISlider *aslider=[[UISlider alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 370, 220, 20)];

volumeSlider=aslider;

[volumeSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(volumeSliderMoved:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[self.view addSubview:volumeSlider];

}

-(void)volumeSliderMoved:(UISlider *)sender

{

self.audioPlayer.volume=[sender value];

}
```

Comment: check this one :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435178/how-to-set-volume-control-using-uislider-in-iphone

Comment: what problem you facing exactly,put whole code so get more idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You can save the slider value in `NSUserDefaults`

Try:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad

{

     UISlider *aslider=[[UISlider alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 370, 220, 20)];
     // fetch previous saved volume from NSUserDefaults. If this is first time it will be 0.
     float volume = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"volume"];
     self.audioPlayer.volume = volume;
     volumeSlider.value = volume;
     volumeSlider=aslider;

     [volumeSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(volumeSliderMoved:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

     [self.view addSubview:volumeSlider];

}

-(void)volumeSliderMoved:(UISlider *)sender

{
     // Save the slider value to NSUserDefaults so it can be used next time.
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:[sender value] forKey:@"volume"];
     self.audioPlayer.volume=[sender value];

}
```

**UPDATE**

```
- (void)playNextSong {
      // Do your stuff
      float volume = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"volume"];
     self.audioPlayer.volume = volume;
}
```

Comment: .this is not working for me..thanks for your response

Comment: Why not? What's happening when you use this. As this will keep your slider's value and retrive on next run this is what you need as of I understand. Please let me know if what you get in `volume` in viewDidLoad method on second run.

Comment: i got same problem bro.If i set volume slider at certain position and after i play another song the volume slider go to initial state.

Comment: While initializing your player also set volume as what is the slider value or see while playing next how slider value is changing.